# Can I run bootrec.exe on working Windows 10

Tags: windows, boot

I was unable to start Windows 10 even though I could see Windows 10 logo. I could not repair start-up in the Windows Recovery Console. I restored Windows 10 on safe mode. Now Windows 10 installs but sometimes start button does not work. So I can say that it was not fixed totally and it takes 2-3 minutes to start if it does.

I'd like to ask what I can use to fix start up totally while Windows is running. Can I run bootrec.exe?

Comment: May happen due to disk errors.Try reinstalling but this time fomat with cmd first and run chkdsk

Comment: just reinstall from scratch, making sure you format the destination during setup

Answer (score 0):

bootrec is not available from within running Windows. It is part of recovery which is based on PE, a slimmed Windows OS.

I would suggest you **run setup.exe from installation media**(from running Windows 10) which allows "upgrade" of current Windows 10. Select option to keep user files and installed programs.

This process takes time but there many things which can lead to a not functioning start button and all suggested repairs I could find on internet did not work for a similar problem I had on a Windows 10 installation.